# ManyToMany Fields causing invalid keyword arguments

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

wonder if anyone can help me. I am trying to write a form and view that adds new user profiles to my database. The User model has a ManyToMany field that is pointing to a table called 'Interest', this allows users to choose interests that they have.

**Models**

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()



class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

**View**

```
def add_user(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        submission = User(
            first_name=cd['first_name'],
            last_name=cd['last_name'],
            date_of_birth=cd['date_of_birth'],
            email=cd['email'],
            password=cd['password'],
            course=cd['course'],
            location=cd['location'],
            interests=cd['interests'], #Line that is causing errors
            bio=cd['bio']
        )
        submission.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/add-user/')
else:
    form = AddUserForm()
return render(request, 'adduser.html', {'form': form})
```

**Form**

```
class AddUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'date_of_birth',
        'email',
        'password',
        'course',
        'location',
        'interests',
        'bio',
        ]
    widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }
```

Does anyone have a way to make this work correctly and allow me to create new Users?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, many-to-many fields are not valid as keyword arguments when you're instantiating a model, because actually they refer to a separate linking table and the instances they relate to must already be saved.

However, you don't need to do any of this manually. One of the whole points of using a ModelForm is that it has a `save` method, which takes care of setting all the fields, including the m2m if necessary.

```
if form.is_valid():
    submission = form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/add-user/')
```

However again, you must **never, ever** use what you have done here. You are storing passwords in plain text and that is a serious significant security hole. There's no reason to do this, either: Django includes an authentication framework that takes care of hashing your passwords for you, and is easily extensible. Use that instead.